# `need an appropriate loader` error after running `next build` in postinstall script

Tags: npm, next.js, post-install

Here is the replication repo:
https://github.com/stomvi/nextjs-postinstall-build

Just run:

```
npm i -g git+ssh://git@github.com:stomvi/nextjs-postinstall-build.git
```

I am using next.js as a local web server as a part of a cli tool. I would like to build the next.js server after the tool is installed, so I put `next build` in the `postinstall` script in the `package.json`. The installation failed with an "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file." error.

Using
- next.js v9.0.4
- npm 6.9.0

The error shows that there might not be a `jsx` file loader for this. Local `npm link` works fine.

```
Failed to compile.

./pages/logs/[page].js 11:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
|   return (
>     <Layout>
|       <div className="card filter-container">
|         <div className="card-header">

> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
```

How could I make this work? Currently I just commit the `.next` dir into the repo.